# "Method or data member not found" (VBA Word)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this portion of code below that keeps receiving the "Method or data 
    member not found" error message:

```
If p.myStyle = "Headings_Sub" Then
p.Range.Select

End If
```

Not sure how to solve. Here is the complete code for reference:

```
Sub testCopyPasteVBA()

testCopyPasteVBA Macro

Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim DocTarget As Word.Document
Dim Target As Excel.Workbook
Dim tSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim StrTxt As String
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim p As Paragraph
Dim myStyle As Style

Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
oRng.Start = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("D_Start").Range.End
oRng.End = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("D_End").Range.Start

Set wordDoc = GetObject(, "word.application")
oRng.Select

Set myStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Headings_Sub", _
Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)
With myStyle.Font
.Bold = True
.Italic = False
.Name = "Times New Roman"
.Size = 12
.AllCaps = True

End With

If p.myStyle = "Headings_Sub" Then
p.Range.Select

End If

Selection.Copy

'If Excel is running
On Error Resume Next
Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Err Then
ExcelWasNotRunning = True
Set oXL = New Excel.Application

End If

oXL.Visible = True
Set Target = oXL.Workbooks.Add
Set tSheet = Target.Sheets(1)
tSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`myStyle` is not a property of the Paragraph object

Try:

```
If p.Style = "Headings_Sub" Then
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If that's the case, do I need to change anything in the following code:   Set myStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Headings_Sub", _
 Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)
With myStyle.Font
 .Bold = True
 .Italic = False
 .Name = "Times New Roman"
 .Size = 12
 .AllCaps = True
 
End With

Comment: It would help to edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do. I can't tell from looking at your code what the aim is. Why do you need to use `GetObject()` when you can just reference the built-in `Application` object?

Comment: I'm using GetObject() based on another programmer's recommendation. Essentially, I want the code to automatically highlight any paragraphs/text that meets the font criteria, then copy that text into an Excel spreadsheet. Ideally, each line of text would be its own row when pasted into the Excel sheet.

Comment: If you're running this in Word then you don't need `GetObject()`.  If you're running this in Excel then there are other issues.  There also seems to be a bunch of code missing: for example you declare `p` but never set it to anything.